# Use window.close for closing window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two pages(index.html and main.html). this is index.html body tags:

```
<a href="main.html">main page</a>
```

and in main page I have a button that when click on that button I want close this window but this function not work! How I can do this? and in console give this warning:

```
Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.
```

Comment: And did you open the window ?

Comment: `function(window.close) ` is a syntax error

Comment: 1) it is window.close() and 2) You can only close what you opened with script yourself

Comment: The console message is very clear. Only the script that opened the window is allowed to close it.

Answer (score 0):

This should close the window:

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="Close Window" onClick="window.close()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('closeButton').click(function(){

  window.close();  //only if you opened the window, and are the owner will this work!  

});
```